# TO more accurately detect and TO more efficiently solve a person's problem

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-choice

I'm wondering if we have two adverbs in English in the basic case below:

Knowing a patient's medical history enables a health provider

1. to detect a patient's medical problems more accurately
2. to solve a patient's medical problems more efficiently

​In this case if I want to put point 1. and 2. in one sentence, is it relevant for me to put it:

I> Knowing a patient's medical history enables a health provider **TO more accurately detect** and **more efficiently solve** a patient's medical problems.

or II> Knowing a patient's medical history enables a health provider **TO more accurately detect** and **TO more efficiently solve** a patient's medical problems.

Comment: The 2nd **to** is optional. Another possibility is to write: **Knowing a patient's medical history enables a health provider to detect a patient's medical problems more accurately and (to) solve them more efficiently.** It avoids the split infinitive, if that matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple to-infinitives joined by a common conjunction, like *and* or *or*, you do not have to use *to* again after the first. You can, if you want, but you don't have to. It's a matter of style (which it perhaps to say 'opinion') which is better.

You are splitting the infinitives, but people do that all the time, so I wouldn't worry about it.